# How to Convert object to array of objects in luaScript-KrakenD

Tags: arrays, json, data-transform, krakend, lua-scripting-library

I have mentioned the code in which i have that query.I am requesting you to help me on the same lua or krakend config or Both. (Note Key is not exists)

**LuaScript**

```
  local docDetails = responseData:get("DocDetails")                                                                                                                                 
    -- docDetails:set("D_OffersAddOn", {}) -- Init OffersAddOn is an empty array.
    local discount = {
        ["D_Name"] = "Discount",
        ["D_Price"] = 0,
        ["D_Type"] = "value",
    }
    local D_OffersAddOn = docDetails:get("D_OffersAddOn") 
    -- D_OffersAddOn:set(0,discount)
```

We are getting

```
{
  "0": {
    "D_Name" : "Discount",
    "D_Price" : 0,
    "D_Type" : "value"
  }
}
```

insted of this I am exepecting

```
[
  {
    "D_Name" : "Discount",
    "D_Price" : 0,
    "D_Type" : "value"
  }
]
```

Line 1 --> getting DocDetails from response

Line 2 --> D_OffersAddOn key not exists in DocDetails. So I am creating an empty table

Line 3 --> I am creating the discount object(table)

Line 4 --> Selecting D_OffersAddOn array initially i created

Line 5 --> Now I am adding the discount object into an table as an array.

When I am doing below operation I am getting excepected as string but received as number.

```
-- D_OffersAddOn:set(0,discount)
```

If I am doing

```
docDetails:set("D_OffersAddOn", {discount})
```

then API returns below format.

```
{
  "0": {
    "D_Name" : "Discount",
    "D_Price" : 0,
    "D_Type": "value"
  }
}
```

But I am expecting the below format

```
{
  "DocDetails": {
    "D_OffersAddOn": [
      {
        "D_Name" : "Discount",
        "D_Price" : 0,
        "D_Type" : "value"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've spent several days to figure it out. It's a shame that there is so little documentation from KrakenD in this matter. Here is a working example that creates a new JsonArray and inserts a single element to an existing array

```
      function post_proxy()
      print("postProxy fired!")
      local resp = response.load();
      local data = {}
      local responseData = resp:data()
    
      --Adding new JsonArray
      local array = luaList:new()
      array:set(0,{})
      array:set(1,{})
      array:get(0):set("name","xxx")
      array:get(1):set("name","yyy")
      responseData:set("newArray",array);
      
      --Adding element to existing JsonArray
      local col = responseData:get("collection"); 
      local size = col:len();
      local newArray = luaList:new()
      local j=0
      for i=0,size-1 do
        j=j+1;
        local element = col:get(i)     
        newArray:set(i,element)
      end
      newArray:set(j,{})
      newArray:get(j):set("name","YYY")
      responseData:set("collection", newArray)
      
    end
```